# System of differential equations - stationary solution given u(t) = sin(t)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a system of differential equations given by:

$$x'= Ax+bu$$
$$y = d^Tx$$

I have then been told that if I have an external force $u(t) = e^{st}$,  then the stationary solution is given by: $y(t) = H(s) e^{st} $. My question then is what the stationary solution will be if i have an external force given by $ u(t) = \sin(kt) $ or $ \cos(kt) $ for that sake?

Comment: I would suggest closing the statements with dollar signs. Anything enclosed in dollar signs will get processed by MathJax.

Comment: @Linda; latex  now ok?

Comment: Yes - like that, thanks

Answer (score 1):

As long as $\pm ik$ are not eigenvalues of $A$, the "stationary solution" will be of the form $a(k) \cos(kt) + b(k) \sin(kt)$.

Comment: How exactly would you then find a and b? I found something saying that if you have u(t) = sin(wt), then the solution would be:   $y(t) = Im(H(iw)e^{iwt}) = |H(iw)|*sin((wt)+Arg H(iw))$, but I'm not quite sure how to do this in practice :)

Comment: First find $x$ of the form ${\bf a} \cos(kt) + {\bf b} \sin(t)$ where $\bf a$ and $\bf b$ are vectors.